# angular array observable does not get updated

Tags: angular

I have ts code as below

```
selectedLangs : string[]  = []
selectedLangs$: Observable<string[]> = of(this.selectedLangs);

ngOnInit(){
    this.form.get( 'languages' ).valueChanges
        .pipe(
            takeUntil( this._unSubscribeAll ),
            tap( langs => {
                this.selectedLangs = [];
                if( langs ) {
                    langs.forEach( ( lang: IOption ) => {
                        if( this.selectedLangs.find( f => f === lang ) === undefined ) {
                            this.selectedLangs.push( lang )
                        }
                    } )
                }
            } )
        )
        .subscribe();
}
```

html

```
<small>{{(selectedLangs$ | async)}}</small>
```

Should my html be updated if I am changing the value of the array?

Comment: In general you do not want to use another local variable `selectedLangs` just to save the data. Instead, you can return a map with the required filters and assign it to `selectedLangs$`. If you could provide a stackblitz with the code you can easily get more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
selectedLangs$: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

ngOnInit() {
  this.form.get('languages').valueChanges.pipe(
    takeUntil(this._unSubscribeAll),
    tap((langs: IOption[]) => {
      const uniqueLangs = [...new Set(langs)];
      this.selectedLangs$.next(uniqueLangs);
    })
  ).subscribe();
}
```